Using std::hash with variant replacement on C++14
I'm backporting some code from C++17 to C++14. One part of the code looks like this:
std::size_t operator()(const OpenXLSX::XLCellValue& value) const noexcept
{
    return std::hash<std::variant<std::string, int64_t, double, bool>> {}(value.m_value);
}

Since variant isn't available in C++14 I'm using this variant implementation as a substitute. So I've rewritten the code like this:
std::size_t operator()(const OpenXLSX::XLCellValue& value) const noexcept
{
    return std::hash<mapbox::util::variant<std::string, int64_t, double, bool>> {}(value.m_value);
}

However, it doesn't compile. I'm getting the following error:
error: use of deleted function 'std::hash<mapbox::util::variant<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, long long int, double, bool> >::hash()'

Any idea how to fix this line for C++14?

Visit the variant and return the "inner" hash (possibly combined with current index)?

@Jarod42 Got some code? I'm not experienced with C++ at all.

Don't know mapbox, but assuming same API than std: return mapbox::util::visit([](const auto& v){ return std::hash<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>>(v); }, value.m_value).

@Jarod42 Thanks, but for some reason I'm getting the error that mapbox::util doesn't have a member named visit. I don't quite understand that because when looking at the mapbox variant implementation, there clearly is a member named visit in the namespace mapbox::util. See here: https://github.com/mapbox/variant/blob/a5a79a594f39d705a7ef969f54a0743516f0bc6d/include/mapbox/variant.hpp#L835 Any idea why gcc still complains about not finding visit?

Hmm, mapbox does seem to define std::hash for its variant type.  Perhaps you are missing an include?  Can you show a [mre]?

...and the visit function is spelled mapbox::util::variant::visit

@DrewDormann Thanks for the pointer with std::hash being defined in mapbox. I was using the latest release 1.1.3 which apparently doesn't have it. I've now upgraded to the variant implementation in their master branch and now it works. Problem solved! Thanks a lot guys!

This question is not edited, amd I see no problem in its current form. The downvote is surprising. Ans I fail to see the ratoinale behind a closing vote. Is there any explanation?
